# Read Grayscale raster in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, raster, tiff

I have a raster image which contains only one band. I am trying to apply histogram equalization on this raster. The problem i cannot read it as grayscale. if i read it as unchanged it show the shape and the values.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('blur3.tif',cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
print(img.shape)
```

shape
(1678, 1064)

But when i change the code to read grayscale it shows empty.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('blur3.tif',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

Comment: cannot reproduce. Tried importing a tiff image with your code and correctly shows a non empty shape, in my case (434, 650). You say it shows empty, what does `print(img.shape)` print in the screen for the second code in your case?

Comment: `shape (1678, 1064)` -- single channel, it's already grayscale, even when read with `IMREAD_UNCHANGED`.

Comment: so you're saying UNCHANGED works but GRAYSCALE fails? there may be a bug. GRAYSCALE tells whatever library to decode as grayscale. perhaps the tiff library/backend is confused by that instruction when facing an already-grayscale file. please provide a grayscale tiff to try this against. also check the version of OpenCV you are using.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JcuWO02njsloiVbwFK4Ho63T8k-4R3Yb/view?usp=sharing

Here is the file

Comment: have you ever seen this message? **`cv::TiffDecoder::readData OpenCV TIFF: TIFFRGBAImageOK: Sorry, can not handle images with 32-bit samples`** (IMREAD_GRAYSCALE or default flags) -- your file, with UNCHANGED, reads to be `dtype=float32`. so reading does work in principle. it's just getting confused about desired conversion. -- also note: that file contains about 32% NaN values

Comment: I havenot seen the message. what should i do to make it grayscale to apply the histo gram equalisation.Should i convert the image to 8 bit?

Comment: use IMREAD_UNCHANGED and that's it. you know that works. why do you want something else? -- you didn't say that histogram equalization threw any error. you said you had trouble with imread(), but that was already resolved when you asked the question because IMREAD_UNCHANGED gave you data